# Referencing external assembly fails

Tags: f#, azure-functions

I can't get referencing a private assembly working. I've followed the documentation, but it still fails with the error message:

```
2016-09-29T19:43:08.615 startup(2,1): error FS82: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Backend.dll". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. (Code=MSB3245)
```

Here is the run.fsx file:

```
#r "Backend.dll"

open System
open System.IO
open System.Net
open System.Net.Http.Headers
open System.Collections.Generic
open CoP

let createResponse json =
    let responseJson = Request.handleJson json
    let response = new HttpResponseMessage()
    response.Content <- new StringContent(responseJson)
    response.StatusCode <- HttpStatusCode.OK
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType <- MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
    response

let Run (req: HttpRequestMessage) =
    async {
        let! json = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        return createResponse json
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

I've also placed the Backend.dll in a bin folder inside the same folder as the function.

[image: azure function folder structure]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you ran into a bug with private assembly resolution in the Azure Functions F# implementation.
I've opened this issue for tracking and will have a fix included in the next release:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/733

In the meantime, you *should* be able to reference your private assembly by using:

`#r "bin/Backend.dll"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: The fix has been merged in and will be deployed with the next release. Thanks for reporting this!

Answer (score 3):

If that was a question about `.fsx` scripts alone, I'd say you're missing the part where you tell FSI where to look for the dll to reference:

```
#I "bin"
#r "BackEnd.dll"
```

Is there anything Azure does to put the `.\bin` folder within the context reachable by `#r` directive?

Comment: Didn't work. Funny enough, when I access the folder and run the run.fsx file it seems to work fine (except for it not finding one of the namespaces), but the azure function log shows the same error.

Comment: Really seems like a bug though. According to the documentation it should just work. I guess I should post a bug report.

Comment: @RobinHeggelundHansen: I've just taken a look at the documentation, and I agree that what you have should just work. I'd assume that `bin` folder is passed to the `fsi.exe` as a search path through a command-line argument behind the scenes, which should have the same effect as `#I`.